# ng new を実行すると SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ターミナルで `npm install -g angular-cli` と打ち込みインストールしました。
そして `ng new m` を実行したところ、次のようなエラーが出てきました。

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:571
      throw reason;
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Function.Project.closestSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:539:16)
    at Function.Project.projectOrnullProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:566:20)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/index.js:40:25)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/cli/index.js:38:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng:103:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:47:14
    at process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:174:43)
    at ondir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:189:17)
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:70:43)
    at onex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:93:31)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:23:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

もう一度angular-cliを再インストールしてましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
解決方法がわかる方がいらしたら教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プロジェクトを作成されようとしているディレクトリの上位にpackage.jsonファイルが置かれていませんでしょうか？
一度以下のようなお試しディレクトリを作成し、そこでコマンドを実行してみてください

```
mkdir ~/Tmp
cd ~/Tmp
ng new m
```

Comment: 新しく作って、package.jsonなしでターミナルでやってみましたが、駄目でした。

Comment: そうですか残念です。エラーが出ている原因がpackage.jsonをJSON.parseしようとしてエラーが発生しているようでした。なので、カレントディレクトリか、またはそれより上のディレクトリに存在する不正なpackage.jsonを読み込んでしまったものと推測しました。念のための確認ですがホームディレクトリにpackage.jsonを置いてたりしませんでしょうか？

Comment: h試しにparseのエラー箇所(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:539:16)を強制的にエラーを吐くように修正し、ng newのコマンドを実行してみました。package.jsonが見つからなければエラー箇所は通らず、package.jsonが見つかった場合のみエラーが発生したため、どこかのpackage.jsonを読み込んでいるのは間違いなさそうです。

Comment: 言われたとおり、ホームディレクトリを見てみたところpackage.jsonがホームディレクトリにありました！
ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決されたようで何よりです。「回答を承認」していただくと他のユーザのために役立つかもしれません。